# How to extract sound from an application program

Tags: windows

An application that I have has a song played as its background music. I would like to extract it so that I could use it for non-commercial purposes.

Is there any tool out there which can do this? Or any Workaround?

Comment: No sound files (*.wav, *.ogg, etc.) in any of the application's folders?

Comment: I second `Isxek's` suggestion to look for audio files in the app folder. You could even name the app here and someone might already know the detail.

Comment: @Isxek, it is a standalone file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Below advice is for Windows 7, if you are using XP there is a small note regarding use on XP)

It is possible to do this using free audio editing/recording software [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) and features built into windows.

First you'll want to right click on the volume icon on on your task bar, by the clock and go to recording devices.

Next, right click on the box that lists your input devices and check "Show Disabled Devices" and  "Stereo Mix" should show up, right click on that and click "Enable"

Finally, go into Audacity, in on the toolbar, you can choose Stereo Mix as your recording device. Once you hit the red circle for record, Audacity will begin to record whatever is coming out of your speakers/earphones/default output device.

As for Windows XP/Vista, in Audacity there should be the option for "What You Hear" as a recording device, which doesn't require you to go through the settings and enable Stereo Mix.

Answer (score 0):

You can record it like this: http://www.pixelmetrics.com/Tips/AudBlank/index.php

Comment: What does the link say? Link-only answers are rather discouraged here. Also, note that these instructions are only useful for a commercial software.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "PE Explorer" software for windows,in order to extract a sound from an application.

[The icon image of PE explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi64i.png)

Comment: Cool, read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.